# How to the get primary key in API using a javascripts

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Im using Django classbased views CRUD but my frontend is DataTables API RestFramework, My problem is how can I get the Primary Key per rows to Edit and Delete the Data? I can display all the data in DataTables but I can't edit and delete since primary key is not found.
Thank You.

**JS**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/api/mlist/?format=datatables",
        "columns": [
            { 
            "data": "A_Id",
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<a href="/List/Details/' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            return data;
            }
            },
      });
</script>
```

**Table.html**

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" data-server-side="true" data-ajax="/api/mlist/?format=datatables">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Act No</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**API list**

```
GET /api/mlist/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2377,
            "A_Id": "VML2020-000000",
        }
       ]
}
```

Comment: can you paste a 'list' response sample received from Django?

Comment: already paste. thanks

Comment: Isn't data.id the primary key?

Comment: I tried but not working